# Xpages error with accessing sessionScope var

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a strange and intermittent error with my Xpages app.

I am extensively using sessionScope variables for various housekeeping items in my app, like navigation and layout titles.

From time to time my app blows up because one of my sessionScope values is null - but it should not be null.

The code blows up on an include page in my main Xpage:

What I am trying to accomplish is dynamically load a page in the facet_1 of an appLayout.

```
<xp:include id="include1" xp:key="LeftColum">
                <xp:this.pageName><![CDATA[${javascript:var selPage:String = sessionScope.selectedPage;
var pageType:String = sessionScope.pageType[selPage];

if (pageType == "0")
{navKey = "ccAppNav"}

if (pageType == "9")
{var capSelPage = selPage.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + selPage.substring(1);
navKey = "ccAppNav" + capSelPage}

navKey + ".xsp"}]]></xp:this.pageName>
            </xp:include>
```

It works perfectly for awhile, but then randomly blows up as the value session.selectedPage is null. I am almost certain I am not setting the value to null anywhere in the code.

Oddly, I am also seeing this error near the null error.

"Xpage State data not available for /xpApp because no control tree was found in the cache."

That sounds to me like Xpages has flushed the sessionScope values.

Comment: HI Bryan, is this issue resolved at your end? what are configuration you are using on the server side and database side? Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Prashant, I assume you are having the same issue. One thing I did was to lengthen my timeout, as Paul suggested below. Eventually I abandoned the SessionScope way to keep my navigation state as it proved to be too problematic.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thank you for reply. In my case I can't go away with sessionScope variable. Can you please send me the configuration that you are using for timeouts? @ which place these values to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure Session Timeout and Application Timeout in xsp.properties is greater than HTTP timeout. Otherwise the user will not be prompted to log in again, but the sessionScopes and applicationScopes could get removed.

Also, the same can happen if someone else refreshes design of the application or cleans the application.

Comment: Paul, this makes tremendous sense. I had no value in there at all, and it seems our http server timeout is something like 180 seconds. That would explain the randomness of it. So I assume application is for appScope and session for sessionScope, right? I am changing those two values to 5 minutes and I will see if I get no errors. Also, I am in XPinC.

Comment: Okay, XPiNC has other weirdnesses. If you change the application in Designer and build, it dumps it from memory. But that throws an error 500, which would be different to the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: Bryan - also it looks like from your code you're using sessionScope to determine some kind of navigation "state".  That could bite you later on depending on how your users use the app.  For instance if they want to run the app but open a page in a second tab to check something else - there's only ONE sessionScope.  So that MIGHT mess you up.  Be careful.

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry, I am new to this. Can you please show where are these configurations? screen shot would help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Application Configuration > Xsp Properties, on the General tab.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you on this. 
Is this configuration ideal or any changes advised? 

Inside Server Document: 
HTTP persistent connections: Disabled
Persistent connection timeout: 180 seconds
Request timeout: 60 seconds

Inside Application Configuration -> XSP Properties: 
Application Timeout: 60 minutes
Session Timeout: 60 minutes 
Persist sessions between requests is selected.

Comment: XPages Portable Command Guide / Mastering XPages 2nd Edition are the best references for configurations and to give you the full details to make the correct decision for any given application.